# Add colums form a 2d array to another 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i've 2 2d array (array1 and array2), that are 2 tables with like 5 columns each.

I need to edit array1 by adding the columns form array 2 in order to obtain an arry that is a table with 10 columns

example:

```
array1 [1,1,1,1,1]
       [2,2,2,2,2]
       [3,3,3,3,3]

array2 [a,a,a,a,a]
       [b,b,b,b,b]
       [c,c,c,c,c]

new array1 [1,1,1,1,1,a,a,a,a,a]
           [2,2,2,2,2,b,b,b,b,b]
           [3,3,3,3,3,c,c,c,c,c]
```

Thnak's a lot for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate and use [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to concat the other values.

```js
var array1 = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]],
    array2 = [['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'], ['c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']];

array1.forEach(function (a, i) {
    Array.prototype.splice.apply(a, [a.length, 0].concat(array2[i]));
});

console.log(array1);
```

Comment: Thank a lot, it works sweet, i've tried by myself the forEach function but it seems i wasn't able to come up with a working code. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

in case the two array has the same lengths then you can safely use this

```
var arr1 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]];
var arr2 = [["a","b","c"], ["d","e","f"], ["g","h","i"], ["j", "k","l"]];

var narr = [];
for(var ii = 0, len = Math.min(arr1.length, arr2.length); ii < len; ii++) {
   narr[ii] = arr1[ii].concat(arr2[ii]);
}
```

this will create a new array with the length equals to the minimum length of the two arrays **arr1** & **arr2**

the result will be :

```
[1,2,3,"a","b","c"]
[4,5,6,"d","e","f"]
[7,8,9,"g","h","i"]
```

if you are not sure they has the same length you can simply change to this code

```
var arr1 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]];
var arr2 = [["a","b","c"], ["d","e","f"], ["g","h","i"], ["j", "k","l"]];

var narr = [];
for(var ii = 0, len = Math.max(arr1.length, arr2.length); ii < len; ii++) {
   narr[ii] = arr1[ii] ? arr1[ii].concat(arr2[ii]) : arr2[ii];
}
```

the result will be

```
[1,2,3,"a","b","c"]
[4,5,6,"d","e","f"]
[7,8,9,"g","h","i"]
["j","k","l"]
```

Comment: Thank you! Since you rightly questioned about the same length of the array i've a bit more complex question ^_^.... do you think it could be possibile to match the 2 arrays for a column before join? (like SQL join function)